# How to run a pure c++ program in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new in Qt and tried to start to write a simple pure C++ program in it.
I created a new project and my .pro file looks like below:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = testgraph
QT = core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
SOURCES += \
main.cpp
```

and my main.cpp file is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cout << "type an integer: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "you have typed: " << n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and then I pressed the Build button and then Run. 
It seems like the program is working but it could't reach to assigning n the value I had just typed in,

[image]

after I typed 4 and pressed Enter, I expected it to break the line and return "you have typed 4" but the cursor just started a new line and nothing happened.

Is this because something wrong in .pro file?

Comment: not the problem but if it worked the output would be only "you have typed" (you forgot the `n` in the output)

Comment: @idclev463035818 thank you for pointing this out, I just edited this.

Answer (score 3):

Your `.pro` file shows that you have created a GUI app but your requirement is to create a pure C++ project.

Follow these steps:

1. Open `File` menu
2. Select `New Project`
3. Select `Non-Qt Project` from the dialog box
4. Select `Plain C++ Application` from the list on the right

After setting this up, your code should run.

The project wizard will offer to select a build system. If your project is a CMake or makefile project, select accordingly. Otherwise, you can select QMake and it'll generate a makefile for you.

Comment: Thank you! It works. but one more may-sound-stupid question. After I run it, it keeps opening my terminal to give the output, is there anyway I can have the output right in Qt interface?

Comment: By the way, I recreated the project as a non-qt one, in the .pro file, the template is still an app but CONFIG is different.

Comment: @Veronica: You're welcome! Yes. it does by default. Go to `Projects`, select `Run` and uncheck `Run in Teminal`. That should solve this.

Comment: @Veronica: Because you selected QMake as your default build system. You can write your own CMake or Makefile configuration and use that. But, I'd suggest using the default configuration with QMake now. You can choose later when you've a better understanding of the other build systems.

Comment: Apparently this is Windows only problem [dosc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-common-projects.html#building-an-application)

Comment: @pptaszni: Which one?

Comment: The one described in the link I posted. "The app template tells qmake to generate a Makefile that will build an application" - OK great, which means it's executable. But later: "windows - The application is a Windows GUI application." and "console - (...) Windows console application". Only on Windows it's necessary to specify it.

Comment: @pptaszni: I believe the term _Windows_ here is referring to an OS that supports the windowing system to work with GUI applications. The line above this section states exactly that "Platform-specific variables are not described here.".